# Split a non delimited, and variable length string

Tags: c#, parsing

given the following string

```
38051211)JLRx(0x04>0x01):JL_PAGE_INFO(0x63,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x00,0x73,0x00,0x00,0x0A,0x01,0x01,0xF2,0x01)
```

How can I split it so I can use each split in a listview column?

I can use split at the : for example but then I need to split at the next ( and each value after split using the ,.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, its how I add the 2nd and 3rd and so on parts I am struggling with

```
 {
    if (line.Contains("JLTx"))
    {
        string[] JLTx = line.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        listView1.Items.Add(JLTx[0]);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(JLTx[1]);                       
    }
}
```

So using the following regex

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*)JLTx\((.*)\):(JL_[(A-Z)_]*)\((.*)\)");
```

I cant seem to split at the : as not in any of the matches. Where am I going wrong

Thanks all

Comment: Use a loop to split through each sub-item.

Comment: Sounds like you dont want to "split" the string, it sounds like you want to "parse" it.  Splitting usually means there is a common delimiter to "split" on.  You might want to look into Regex to get the csv data out, then use `Split()`

Comment: Yeah parsing is correct, my bad.

Comment: Could you show us the structure of the data you would like to achieve? Even as a text mockup would be useful.

Comment: The sample above is how the data looks, although the length maybe different regarding the ( , , , , ).  The first split/parse would be 38051211)JLRx(0x04>0x01): then JL_PAGE_INFO and each value after , in the brackets. Hope that is clear. Thank you

Comment: This question is not related to list views or winforms at all. The actual problem you have is unrelated to the UI output method you want to use, so these tags should not be there...

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't start out an expert at this. Point noted

Comment: You show the input data, but not the desired output. We need to know what you want to put in each listview column.

Comment: Hi NetMage, so column 1 would be "38051211)JLRx(0x04>0x01):" column 2 would be "JL_PAGE_INFO". These 2 fields always vary but the last set of ( & ) are always the same. So all columns after 2 would have each of the values between the ( ) in individual columns. For example column 3 would have "0x63" column 4 "0x00" and so forth. Being relatively new my research and reading isnt coming up good for me. Although I am maybe not searching for the correct thing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This kind of question comes up all the time on SO. Just write a lexer! It's not that hard to do.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks Eric, I have read and cant see the wood for the trees! I will indeed read some more :(. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out you have a lot of options for parsing this into some header friendly format.  @Johns answer above would work if your JL_PAGE_INFO is stable for all input.  You could also use a regex. A lot of it depends on how stable your input data is.  Here is a example using string functions to create the list of headers you described.

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            yield break;
        if (')' != input[input.Length - 1])
            yield break;

        int colon = input.IndexOf(':');

        string pageData = input.Substring(colon + 1);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageData))
            yield break;

        int open = pageData.IndexOf('(');

        if (colon != -1 && open != -1)
        {
            yield return input.Substring(0, colon+1);

            foreach (var token in pageData.Substring(open+1, pageData.Length - (open + 1) - 1).Split(','))
                yield return token;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the second item of your split string - JLTx[1] - is always going to be JL_PAGE_INFO(...) I would try this:

```
string[] mystring = JLTx[1].Replace("JL_PAGE_INFO(","").Replace(")","")Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```